# how to comment jinja code in a state sls file (# not working)

Tags: salt-stack

i am having trouble commenting out jinja code in a state file,
i have a for loop in sls file

```
{% for user_name in salt['pillar.get']('userlist') %}

get_user:
    - Some code here
    ....

{% endfor %}
```

i am commenting it out with `#`, but the loop still running when i execute state in a minion.

```
# {% for user_name in salt['pillar.get']('userlist') %}

get_user:
    - Some code here
    ....

# {% endfor %}
```

what i am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are commenting `jinja` code using `YAML` comment (`#`), and the reason your `for` loop is still running is because [by default SLS files are rendered as Jinja templates](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/#renderers) first, and then parsed as YAML documents.

You need to use `jinja` comment instead, `{# ..... #}`

```
{# {% for user_name in salt['pillar.get']('userlist') %} #}

get_user:
    - Some code here
    ....

{# {% endfor %} #}
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose them in `{# ... #}`:

```
{# {% for user_name in salt['pillar.get']('userlist') %} #}

get_user:
    - Some code here
    ....

{# {% endfor %} #}
```